# Make method return something just for the sake of testing it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have an async Task method which doesn't really return anything because all it does is migrate some data.
However, I'd like to somehow test the method and all I can think of is making the method return a bool when it is completed (true if it does migrate the data, otherwise false), although it's completely unnecessary for the process, it's just for the xunit test.
Is it considered bad practice to do so? Or is there perhaps another way to test an async Task?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you don't test what the method _returns_, but what it _does_. if it's migrating data, then you setup before-testdata, run your method, then check if the data fits the expected result. (if that's not possible, the way of least effort is to let the method throw exceptions when stuff goes wrong, and test if it runs without throwing an exception)

Comment: Just test whether the data is migrated to the place it should be after the method finished. Or is this  not possible for some reason? Also just testing the return value is not sufficient: Your method might have a bug that it returns true even if it didn't migrate the data.

Comment: Note that method `async Task` is returning value of type `Task` which you can examine of it succeed or failed(thrown an exception)

Comment: Please share with us your simplified migration method and how did you try to tackle the testing and where did you stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, do not add a return value.

If you are performing an integration test, you should actually set up test data, run the method, and check to see if the data were migrated, e.g. by interrogating the database or reading the file from disk and comparing it to the expected results.

If you are performing a unit test, you should mock or stub out the portion of the code that persists the data, and check to ensure the proper calls were made (i.e. called in the right order and with correct arguments, given the inputs to the method under test).